# How to select only first available checkbox selenium

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

i am new with Selenium and i try to select and click on the first checkbox from the datatable
[image]

[image]

i could get the id of the checkbox with the following code

```
 public void AssignToCompany()
    {
        var checkedRow = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox'][1]"));
        checkedRow.Click();
    }
```

but when i run the function i get the below error and the checkbox will not be cklicked!
[image]

Comment: Please provide a web link

Comment: @Ruyut i have already updated the post the html source. Thansk

Answer (score 1):

Update: element not interactable means that your element is hidden and can't be clicked, you should click another xpath

Try this xpath
`Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[contains(@class,'ui-chkbox-icon')][1]"))`

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work for me i got same error,it shows all the checkbox span and the index not working!

Comment: Maybe it's because of shadow dom, try to look up for ```.//p-checkbox[@name='supplierCheckbox']```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the first checkbox by using the code(Have used brackets to limit the xpath to the first index):

```
public void AssignToCompany()
{
    var checkedRow = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]"));
    checkedRow.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindElements`.

```
public void AssignToCompany()
{
    var checkedRow = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])"))[0];
    checkedRow.Click();
}
```